# Allow an application to only run on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to write an application that will only run if it can verify that it is running on an AWS EC2 instance? How does an application verify that it is, in fact, running on AWS?

Comment: You could query the [metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html).  The bigger question is why?

Comment: per @AnonCoward you can look at the instance metadata to kind-of see if it's running on EC2 but that can easily be spoffed. What are you trying to do? what is the application written in?

Comment: My company is looking at various cloud deployment options for our commercial software and someone asked if there was a way to disable the software is a customer tried to move it off of AWS.

Answer (score 0):

This is reference from official [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/identify_ec2_instances.html#inspect-uuid)

You can get the system UUID and look for the presence of the characters "ec2" or "EC2" in the beginning octet of the UUID. Furthermore, for EC2 instances that are not using Amazon Linux 2, the distribution's implementation of SMBIOS might represent the UUID in little-endian format, therefore the "EC2" characters do not appear at the beginning of the UUID.

Use the following command to get the UUID using the Desktop Management Interface (DMI):

```
sudo dmidecode --string system-uuid
```

OUTPUT `EC2E1916-9099-7CAF-FD21-01234ABCDEF`

the UUID starts with "EC2", which indicates that the system is probably an EC2 instance.

ALTERNATIVELY

the goal is to tell if it's an EC2 instance OR another kind of cloud instance, like google, then dmidecode works very nicely and no networking is required

```
# From an amazon ec2 VM
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
4.2.amazon
```

if you need more ways follow this answer https://serverfault.com/a/903599